# "element Edit text not allowed" Error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--here the error showing-->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="Enter email"
        android:id="@+id/emailEdit" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="Enter password"
        android:id="@+id/passwordEdit"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:text="Log in"
        android:id="@+id/login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i am getting the error on code that "Element Edit text not allowed here" please help me to solve the issue.. and also preview not opening on android studio

Comment: Try *running Invalidate Caches / Restart..* in your AndroidStudio

Comment: can you show your build.gradle?

Comment: Add width line of code of linearlayout to next line

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your XML code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to these versions.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 28
```